# Sort By Price: Low to High & High to Low using Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, price, sort, listing

I want to add filter option: `Sort By Price`, `Low to High` & `High to Low` in sort by box.

Comment: this is not working on magento 2.2.5
anybody help me ?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/137133)

Answer (score 4):

Override phtml file of Magento_Catalog module in design:
`../app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/toolbar/sorter.phtml`

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * Product list toolbar
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
 */
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\ProductList\Toolbar;
?>
<div class="toolbar-sorter sorter">
    <label class="sorter-label" for="sorter"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Sort By') ?></label>
    <select id="sorter" data-role="sorter" class="sorter-options">
        <option value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo 'short_by'; ?>"
            <?php if ($block->isOrderCurrent('short_by')): ?>
                selected="selected"
            <?php endif; ?>
            >
            <?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__("Sorting")) ?>
        </option>
        <?php foreach ($block->getAvailableOrders() as $_key => $_order): ?>
                    <?phpif($_key == "price"):?>
                            <option value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_key.'&product_list_dir=asc'; ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent('price') && $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'asc'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                            <?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__("Preis - Low to High")) ?>
                            </option>

                            <option value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_key.'&product_list_dir=desc'; ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent('price') && $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                            <?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__("Price - High to Low")) ?>
                            </option>
                    <?php elseif($_key == "position"):?>
                    <?php elseif($_key == "short_by"):?>
                    <?php else:?>
                        <option value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_key; ?>"
                            <?php if ($block->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?>
                                selected="selected"
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            >
                            <?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__($_order)) ?>
                        </option>
                    <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

For %3D added issue with Amasty_Shopby add below code into `am_ShopByAjax.js` file(line no 48):

```
/* added custome code */
   link = decodeURIComponent(link);
   var urlPaths = link.split('?');
   var urlParams = urlPaths[1] ? urlPaths[1].split('&') : [];
   var paramcheck = urlParams[0].split("=");

   if (paramcheck[0] == "product_list_dir") {
       var urlPathsParams = urlPaths[1].split('&');
       urlPathsParams.splice(0, 1);;
       var urlParams = urlPathsParams.join('&');
       urlPaths[1] = urlParams;
       link = urlPaths.join('?');
   }
/*end*/
```

Inform me if have any issue!

Comment: Hi @Ronak the Url is looking like this 
product_list_order=price%26product_list_dir%3Ddesc and not working

Comment: have you used Any Amasty Module?

Comment: yes i am using Amasty shopby

Comment: Yes,  that is create this issue, I had same issue like this else this code will work fine. you can test this after disable Amasty module.

Comment: so now how can i make it work??

Comment: /app/code/Amasty/Shopby/view/frontend/web/js/amShopbyAjax.js test this file, you may get solution.

Comment: Check my updated Answer @gajjalasandeep

Comment: Hi @Ronak i will look this and will give you the response. thanks for responding.

Comment: Hi @Ronak I have added the code to am_ShopByAjax.js still the problem persists. Thanks for responding.

Comment: okay! Thanks! But it works for me!

Comment: Is there any another solution??

Comment: I have the same issue in url but i'm using any Amasty extension.How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar using following code. 
**app/code/Anshu/Sortby/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Anshu_Sortby',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Anshu/Sortby/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Anshu_Sortby" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/Anshu/Sortby/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">   <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" type="Anshu\Sortby\Block\Catalog\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" />
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config" type="Anshu\Sortby\Model\Config" />
</config>
```

**app/code/Anshu/Sortby/Model/Config.php**

```
<?php

namespace Anshu\Sortby\Model;

class Config extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config
{

    /**
     * Retrieve Attributes Used for Sort by as array
     * key = code, value = name
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAttributeUsedForSortByArray()
    {
        $options = ['position' => __('Most Popular')];
        foreach ($this->getAttributesUsedForSortBy() as $attribute) {
            /* @var $attribute \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\AbstractAttribute */
            $options[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute->getStoreLabel();
        }

        $options['position'] = __('Most Popular');
        $options['price'] =  __('Price: Low to High');
        $options['price_desc'] = __('Price: High to Low');
        return $options;
    }

}
```

**app/code/Anshu/Sortby/Block/Catalog/Product/ProductList/Toolbar.php**

```
<?php

namespace Anshu\Sortby\Block\Catalog\Product\ProductList;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\ProductList;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\ProductList\Toolbar as ToolbarModel;

class Toolbar extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
{
    /**
     * Set collection to pager
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setCollection($collection)
    {
        $this->_collection = $collection;

        $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());

        // we need to set pagination only if passed value integer and more that 0
        $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
        if ($limit) {
            $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
        }
        if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
            switch ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
                case 'price':
                    $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), 'ASC');
                    break;

                case 'price_desc':
                    $this->_collection
                            ->getSelect()
                            ->order('price_index.price DESC');

                default:
                    //$this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
                    $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), 'DESC');
                break;
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Hi @anu mishra i will look this and will give you the response..thanks for responding.

Comment: Hi @anu mishra the DESC is not working.

Comment: I have checked in default Magento2.1.5 and it is working for me.

Comment: i am currently working on magento 2.1.9